# "IndexError: string index out of range" RLE in python

Tags: python, compression, run-length-encoding, rle

if i input **A3B4** program its run but i input **A10B13** so program will error index out of range, so how to fix the code without library and use based the code.

```
Char = input ("Input Char : ")
Total = len(Char)
Decompress =""

for i in range (0, Total,2):
    Loop = int(Char[i+1])
    for j in range (0, Loop):
        Decompress = Decompress + Char [i]
        
print("Output : ",Decompress)
```

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner can you fix the code without using a library

Comment: Created the answer below. Do you really need this variable of type int.
If you make it a string, then there will be no problem?

Comment: If something is unclear, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
Char = input("Input Char : ")
Total = len(Char)
Decompress = ""

for i in range(0, Total, 2):
    print('i', i)
    print('Char[i + 1]', Char[i + 1])
    Loop = int(Char[i + 1])
    for j in range(0, Loop):
        Decompress = Decompress + Char[i]

print("Output : ", Decompress)
```

You are doing the conversion of 'B' to int. The symbol cannot be converted to a number. I made a printout of this particular line. Run the code and see.
Also, when you have a string with an even number, there is no way out of the array.
But, if, for example, enter 7 characters, then there will be an exit outside the array.

Indexing of arrays starts from 0. That is, the seventh element will have an index of six.
Added a line where indexes are printed print('i', i).And the string asks for +1(Char[i + 1]). That is, 1 more. Having an array of 7 elements in size, we request a non-existent 8.

```
Char = input("Input Char : ")
Total = len(Char)
Decompress = ""

for i in range(0, Total, 2):
    print('i', i)
    print('Char[i + 1]', Char[i + 1])
    Loop = str(Char[i + 1])
    for j in range(0, len(Loop)):
        Decompress = Decompress + Char[i]

print("Output : ", Decompress)
```